# Error while execution powershell code on System Center Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm facing an issue of getting all vms configuration ( using Get-ScVirtualMachine command) into an array from an input file.

The code is this one below

```
$VmsList = Get-Content C:\VmsList.txt
foreach($vm in $VmsList){

$Result += Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name $vm

}
```

And I have this error

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.VM] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
```

At line:3 char:1

- $Result += Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name $vm
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
  ```

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.VM] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:3 char:1

- $Result += Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name $vm
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
  ```

Get-SCVirtualMachine : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The character length (0) of the argument is too short. Specify an argument with a length that
is greater than or equal to "1", and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:39

- $Result += Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name $vm
- ```
                                    ~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-SCVirtualMachine], ParameterBindingValidationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Cmdlets.GetVMCmdlet

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to declare the array `$result = @()`

I resolved the issue.